# a field or property with the name 'PageID' was not found on the selected data source - ALIAS

Tags: c#, sql, eval, alias

my line in gridview

```
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# new System.Text.StringBuilder("<a href=\"/Administration/Pages/EditPage/?pageID=").Append(Eval("PageID")).Append("\">").Append(Eval("Name")).Append("</a>").ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
```

fails with

> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: DataBinding:
>   'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name
>   'PageID'.

i suspect the issue is the alias in datasource

```
SelectCommand="SELECT Menus.ID, Menus.ParentID, Menus.Name, Menus.Slug, Menus.PageTitle, Menus.PageSubTitle, Menus.MenuOrder, Menus.IsHomePage, Menus.IsYourAccountLink, Menus.IsMiniMenu, Menus.IsFooterMenu, Menus.IsHeaderMenu, Menus.CustomerID, Customers.SubDomain, PublicPages.ID AS PageID FROM Menus INNER JOIN Customers ON Menus.CustomerID = Customers.ID INNER JOIN PublicPages ON Menus.ID = PublicPages.HeaderMenuID AND Customers.ID = PublicPages.CustomerID WHERE (Menus.CustomerID = @CustomerFilter)"
```

so how to use it as the alias in:

```
Append(Eval("PageID"))
```

thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one,

```
<%# Container.DataItem.GetColumn("PageId")%>
```

UPDATE1: A second option

```
<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem.GetColumn("PageId"))%>
```

Comment: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'GetColumn' and no extension method 'GetColumn' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)